# How to register and call a schema in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I created schema for my file and calling it as below but it says error that schema is not registered for comments........Is this due to path?

My schema,

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  path = require('path'),
  config = require(path.resolve('./config/config')),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Commentsscheme = new Schema({
  articleid: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId
  },
  fromuser: {
    type: String
  },
  touser: {
    type: String
  },
  comment: {
    type: String
  }
});

mongoose.model('comments', Commentsscheme);
```

My js,

```
   var path = require('path'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  passport = require('passport'),
  Comments = mongoose.model('comments');

/* ------ Inserting a comment  ------ */
exports.insertcomment = function (req, res) {
  var comments = new Comments(req.body);
  console.log(comments)
  comments.status = 1;
  var data = {};
  comments.save(function (err,resl) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return err;
    } 
     data = { status: false, error_code: 0, message: 'Unable to insert' };
    if (resl) {
      data = { status: true, error_code: 0,result: resl, message: 'Inserted successfully' };
    }
      res.json(data);
  });
};
```

I created schema for my file and calling it as below but it says error that schema is not registered for comments........can any one please suggest help,........................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export your model  like below and then require in route file or calling file

module.exports = mongoose.model('comments', Commentsscheme);

Now require it and use to save comments.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that above two codes are in two different files and in same folder.
and
Schema file name is comment.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  path = require('path'),
  config = require(path.resolve('./config/config')),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Commentsscheme = new Schema({
  articleid: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId
  },
  fromuser: {
    type: String
  },
  touser: {
    type: String
  },
  comment: {
    type: String
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', Commentsscheme);
```

and in other js file you will use this schema as follows

```
var path = require('path'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  passport = require('passport'),
  // here you need to put the path/name of the file so that module will load.
  Comments = require('comment.js');


/* ------ Inserting a comment  ------ */
exports.insertcomment = function (req, res) {
  var comments = new Comments(req.body);
  console.log(comments)
  comments.status = 1;
  var data = {};
  comments.save(function (err,resl) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return err;
    } 
     data = { status: false, error_code: 0, message: 'Unable to insert' };
    if (resl) {
      data = { status: true, error_code: 0,result: resl, message: 'Inserted successfully' };
    }
      res.json(data);
  });
};
```